# Comparing 'id' via the findIndex method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

If `todos` of the`todo` object is not found in the array. Add `todo` to the`todos` array. If found, do not add to the board.
Compares if the table is todo with the given index. Returns -1 to me, or false. I do the condition `if (! findObject) {}` should add the object to the array instead of adding it

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7wlg5m

```
const todos = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  }
]

const todo = {
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 3,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}

  let findObject = todos.findIndex(x => x.id === todo.id);
  console.log(findObject);

if(!findObject) {
  let newArray = [...todos];

  newArray.push(todo)
  console.log(newArray)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to Jack Bashford's answer is to use `.find` instead of `.findIndex`.
`.find` returns `undefined` if the todo is not found in the todos array, and `undefined` is a falsy value.

Array.prototype.find() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
let findObject = todos.find(x => x.id === todo.id);
console.log(findObject);

if(!findObject) {
  let newArray = [...todos];

  newArray.push(todo)
  console.log(newArray)
}
```

Working example: https://repl.it/repls/TemporalLividCodegeneration

Answer (score 3):

`findIndex` will return `-1` if the item is not found, and unfortunately, that is not a falsy value - the only falsy number value is 0. All others - including `-1` - are truthy.

```js
console.log(!!-1);
```

So you should check against `-1` in your condition:

```
if (findObject == -1) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **filter** method to filter out matching id. You can do something like this:

```
let findObject = todos.filter(x => x.id === todo.id);
console.log(findObject);

if (!findObject.includes(todo.id)) {  
  let newArray = [...todos];
  newArray.push(todo);
  console.log(newArray);
}
```

You can find out more about filter method from here : [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter]

Hope this helps